# NSUserNotificationCenter in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to create an app that will pop up notification.
I use the NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate in my app like so:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    let NScenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.default        

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.NScenter.delegate = self
        let notification = NSUserNotification.init();
        self.NScenter.deliver(notification)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }
```

I'm trying to execute code when the user press on Yes, No, or any click on the notification.
I tried to use this function instead:

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        print("ok");
        return true;
    }
```

But when I used it the notification just did't show up.

Comment: https://cocoacasts.com/local-notifications-with-the-user-notifications-framework this tutorial will help you.

Comment: Have you tried making a custom `NSUserNotification`?

Comment: thanks, i found a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, when using both function, the notification popup and I can get when the user click on it.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    let NScenter = NSUserNotificationCenter.default        

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.NScenter.delegate = self
        let notification = NSUserNotification.init();
        self.NScenter.deliver(notification)
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return true;
    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        print("ok");
        return true;
    }
}
```